# Python array multiply

Tags: python, floating-point, multiplication

```
hh=[[82.5], [168.5]]
N=1./5
ll=N*hh
```

What I'm doing wrong? I received error :

> "can't multiply sequence by non-int of
>   type 'float'"

I try to add float(), but this is not solve my problem;

I need to multiply each element in array...
thanks to all

---

### **Ok thanks for idea for number * array, but how to multiply array*array, I tried same as number*array, but have problems:

### EDIT 2:**

```
hh=[[82.5], [168.5]]
N=zip(*hh)
ll = [[x*N for x in y] for y in hh]
```

???

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you multiply a sequence by `X` in Python, it doesn't multiply each member of the sequence - what it does is to repeat the sequence `X` times. That's why X has to be an integer (it can't be a float).

What you want to do is to use a list comprehension:

```
hh = [[82.5], [168.5]]
N  = 1.0 / 5
ll = [[x*N for x in y] for y in hh]
```

Comment: how can I implement for 2 arrays ? see on EDIT 2

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to multiply matrices (that is, the matrix product)? Do you want to multiply array elements by position? In both cases, I think you should check out numpy, for cleaner code.

Comment: yes matrix product; no I don't want to use numpy; please understand me

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Well, since matrix product is quite more complex and my math is a little rusty, I can't do a python implementation of that, but you can find some implementations of matrix product functions on Google, e.g.: http://www.syntagmatic.net/matrix-multiplication-in-python/

Answer (score 8):

Well in Python you can do this:

```
>>> [2] * 3
[2, 2, 2]
```

This requires an int type.

What you are looking for is something a kin to `map` or a list comprehension.

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x * 2, [2, 2]))
[4, 4]
>>> [x * 2 for x in [2, 2]]
[4, 4]
```

You can also generator comprehension to do it lazily.

```
(x * 2 for x in [2, 2])
```

Or you can do it a bit Haskellish (albeit without the elegance):

```
>>> import operator
>>> from functools import partial, reduce
>>> add = partial(operator.mul, 2)
>>> list(map(add, [2,2]))
[4, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) array for multiplying the numbers in the array.

```
>>> hh = numpy.asarray([[82.5], [168.5]])
>>> N = 1.0/5
>>> ll = N*hh
>>> ll
array([[ 16.5],
       [ 33.7]])
```

Comment: See the [basic array](http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-4c1d53fe504adc97baf27b65513b4b97586a4fc5) operations for multiplication examples.

Comment: well i try not to use numpy or any other "library" which is not included while I installed IDE