# Python multiply 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays

This is continued from thread:
[Python array multiply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825208/python-array-multiply)

I need to multiply array vs array. I don't want to use "numpy". From previous thread, I learned how to multiply

number*array:

```
hh=[[82.5], [168.5]]
N=1./5
ll = [[x*N for x in y] for y in hh]
```

**But how can I multiply array*array:**  ->**matrix multiplication.**

```
hh=[[82.5], [168.5]]
N=zip(*hh)                                        -> N must be transpose of hh!!!!!
ll = [[[x*z for x in y] for y in hh] for z in N]
```

? thanks

---

### EDIT:

**input:**

```
hh=[[82.5], [168.5]]
N=zip(*hh)                            #N=[(82.5, 168.5)]
```

**output
want: hh*N**

```
[[  6806.25  13901.25]
 [ 13901.25  28392.25]]
```

Comment: What's the problem with using numpy?

Comment: You'd better mention that you're looking for matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use operator.mul and map.

```
from operator import mul
map(mul, list1, list2)
```

Matrix N*hh where N=zip(**hh)

```
>>> hh = [[82.5], [168.5]]
>>> [ [i*j for i in x for j in y] for x in hh for y in zip(*hh) ]
[[6806.25, 13901.25], [13901.25, 28392.25]]

>>> hh = [[2], [4]]
>>> [ [i*j for i in x for j in y] for x in hh for y in zip(*hh) ]
[[4, 8], [8, 16]]

>>> hh = [[2], [4], [6]]
>>> [ [i*j for i in x for j in y] for x in hh for y in zip(*hh) ]
[[4, 8, 12], [8, 16, 24], [12, 24, 36]]

>>> hh = [[1, 2, 4]]
>>> [ [i*j for i in x for j in y] for x in hh for y in zip(*hh) ]
[[1, 2, 4], [2, 4, 8], [4, 8, 16]]

>>> hh = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> [ [i*j for i in x for j in y] for x in hh for y in zip(*hh) ]
[[1, 3, 2, 6], [2, 4, 4, 8], [3, 9, 4, 12], [6, 12, 8, 16]]
```

If you are looking for something else, here is another couple examples to get you started:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [0, 1, 2]
>>> [ x*y for x in a for y in b]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 4, 0, 3, 6]
>>> [[x*y for x in a] for y in b]
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: By far the best and most concise answer.

Comment: well thanks for this it's simple and clear but b must be transpose of a; if I use on your code zip(*b), received errors about it "support iteration" ??

Comment: @Joce, thx, However I may have just successfully polluted it.

Comment: @thaking, can you provide input and output that you would like to see?

Comment: @thaking, awesome.  I have something..not sure if holds up. Let me know.

Comment: @thaking, you're welcome.  The list comprehension cartesian products are handy when needed.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is right, but you can write it down a bit simpler:

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5] # or hh[0]
list_b = [6,7,8,9,0] # or hh[1]
multiplied = [a * b for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)]
```

Also, if you want `/` operator to return float, add `from __future__ import division` at the top of your source.

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension, just like your previous number * array question.

Say you have two arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

First you [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) them to obtain the pairs you wish to multiply:

```
pairs = zip(a,b)
```

This results in `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`.
You can 'unpack' a tuple like this:

```
val1, val2 = (1,4) # val1=1 and val2=4
```

Combining everything together, this would multiple arrays `a` and `b`:

```
c = [val1*val2 for val1,val2 in zip(a,b)]
```

In your example above, `hh` is an array containing your two arrays and the answer becomes:

```
hh=[[82.5], [168.5]]
N=zip(*hh)
ll = [x*y for x,y in N]
```

Comment: this last I know, i want to multiply (matrix * matrix) so result must be matrix, not scalar or number...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous question, I'm assuming you want matrix multiplication, not element-wise multiplication...

```
m = range(len(hh))
n = range(len(N[0]))
p = range(len(N))
ll = [[sum(hh[i][k]*N[k][j] for k in p) for j in n] for i in m]
```

Comment: well received:
    ll = [[sum(hh[i0][j]*N[i][j0] for j in n for i in m) for j0 in n] for i0 in m]
IndexError: list index out of range

Yes i want matrix*matrix  hh*hh(transpose)

Comment: @thaking: Sorry, it was broken. I've amended my answer. It should work with any pair of matrices, MxP * PxN, not just MxN * NxM.