# Cant multiply sequence by Float for Python

Tags: python

I saw this questions a couple other places but all the fixes dont work for me code. If someone could help that would be great.

```
import random
cvalues=[]

for i in range(50):
  cvalues.append(random.randrange(0,16))

float_cvalues=[float(i) for i in cvalues]

print(float_cvalues)

nvalues=[((.4*(float_cvalues)-.8))]
print(nvalues)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? And what is your expected output?

Comment: Basically im trying to take the list of random numbers (float_cvalues) and use that list in order to create a second list (n) by basically doing the calculation .4*value -.8 on every value in the float_cvalues list

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying a sequence in Python is interpreted as an attempt to create multiple sequences, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825208/python-array-multiply).

You can instead use another list comprehension:

```
nvalues=[.4*i-.8 for i in float_cvalues]
```

Or for instance switch to `numpy` arrays.